# Unable to start debugging on the web server 'localhost'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I am having intermittent issues when running a debug session from Visual Studio 2012. This issue is resolved by restarting the IDE.

When I try to debug a website in a given solution, I am presented with an error that reads:

**Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote name could not be resolved: 'localhost'.**

I have no idea why this happens intermittently. Can anyone help? I am running 2012 Premium with one extension - ReSharper.

Thanks.

Comment: for me it was conflicted versions of the .net after a windows update. I've just ran "aspnet_regiis -i" and it worked again

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following solutions:

1. Close Visual Studio and start it again choosing "Run as administrator" option.
2. Delete the obj and bin folders from the solution directory > Rebuild the solution.

I had same issue with my Visual Studio 2017 but it was immediately fixed after I applied these two guidelines. Although, i'm not sure which one of these two worked i.e. only the first one was enough or I must had to follow the second one. Because I couldn't notice the difference after applying the first fix i.e. running visual studio 2017 as an administrator.